# Wang's Bend Simplify in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, simplify, generalization

I am looking for an alternative to ESRI's Simplify Polygons - Bend Simplify method (I only have a Basic License).

Is there an existing QGIS plugin which supports this specific polygon simplifying algorithm?

If not, does anyone have a suggestion for which Generalization algorithm within the Grass `v.generalize` might produce the most similar results?

Comment: Is the method of the same kind than Visvalingam-Whyatt in PostGIS  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyVW.html https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/?

Comment: SImilar, but as I understand it, Visvalingam prioritizes retaining areas, whereas Wangs algorithm prioritizes conservings bends/curves while minimizing vertices, which is more appropriate for my data.

Answer (score 5):

A new [QGIS plugin called Geo Simplification](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geo_sim_processing/) that contains a processing script named Reduce Bend is available in the official QGIS plugin repository.  It is an implementation of the Wang-Muller algorithm, the same algorithm used by the ESRI Bend simplify.  It can simplify lines but also polygons while preserving topology within and between features of the same layer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try mapshaper

Mapshaper's default simplification method uses Visvalingam simplification but weights the effective area of each point so that smaller-angle vertices are preferentially removed, resulting in a smoother appearance.

https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-simplify